# Why Yahoo CSS reset is using "font:inherit"

Tags: css, yahoo, reset

Why Yahoo CSS reset is using `font:inherit` for below tags?

```
address,button,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,input,optgroup,
option,select,strong,textarea,th,var {
    font:inherit
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess it has to do with css inheritance that for some properties like `font-size` which might not be inherited by default (`font` is the css shorthand for the different `font-*` rules).

The [inherit value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance) is used to enforce inheritance of values or to make inherit values of properties which are normally not.

You can see on this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Sh4y9/)** that the first input does not inherit font properties, compared to the second one which has `font: inherit`.

Comment: When I clicked link "fiddle" it shows a error page saying Server not found.

Comment: Indeed, the link is broken. I've put it back. Sorry for that, i don't know what happenned.

Comment: Weird, the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Sh4y9/) is ok and normally accessible...